# Interpreting results from linearmodels PanelOLS .predict() method

Tags: python, panel-data, linearmodels

Suppose I have the following toy data:

```
import pandas as pd
from linearmodels.panel import PanelOLS

y = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]],
    data=[70, 60, 50, 30, 33, 27],
    columns=["y"],
)
y.index.set_names(["Entity", "Time"], inplace=True)

x = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]],
    data=[[100], [89], [62], [29], [49], [23]],
    columns=["X"],
)
x.index.set_names(["Entity", "Time"], inplace=True)
```

And build a model using `PanelOLS` with `entity_effects=True`:

```
model_within = PanelOLS(dependent=y, exog=x, entity_effects=True).fit()
```

And then wanted to use the `predict()` method to see how a new "entity" would be modelled. First creating a new entity with:

```
new_x = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[[3, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3]],
    data=[[40], [70], [33]],
    columns=["X"],
)
new_x.index.set_names(["Entity", "Time"], inplace=True)
```

Then predicting with:

```
model_within.predict(new_x)
```

To get the following output:

|  |  | predictions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Entity | Time |  |
| 3 | 1 | 16.136230 |
|  | 2 | 28.238403 |
|  | 3 | 13.312390 |

According to [Wooldridge, 2012, pg 485](https://economics.ut.ac.ir/documents/3030266/14100645/Jeffrey_M._Wooldridge_Introductory_Econometrics_A_Modern_Approach__2012.pdf), the within estimator is estimating:

[image]

Since this is modelling a **change** in expected y from the average of past y's for this entity, how should the predictions be interpreted? My intuition is that the prediction is saying:
For this new entity, 3, in time period 1, given these X inputs, y at time 1 should be 16 units higher than it's *average* y across all time, for this entity. Is this interpretation correct? How might it be improved?

[linearmodels .predict() documentation](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/panel/panel/linearmodels.panel.model.PanelOLS.predict.html)

Answer (score 0):

Posting results from seeking clarification through the repo:
https://github.com/bashtage/linearmodels/issues/465

"The model is always Y=XB + epsilon + (eta_t ) + (nu_i ). The effects are treated as errors, and so when you predict you get `new_x @ params` and so the entity effects are not used."

So the predictions are for actual values of y, not time-demeaned predictions. However, to achieve time-demeaned predictions, one can create the same model using data that has first been time-demeaned, and pass in new time-demeaned data to predict on.